# Have a record delete itself unless pinged?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm using Microsoft SQL server, and I would like to know if it is possible to somehow add a row to a table which will delete itself after a while, unless "updated" or "pinged".

I am programming a game from where I would like to have some kind of match-spectation system. If you go to http://ingamable.com, you should be able to see what I mean.

So every time I (from a game) start a match, the game sends a request to my webserver to create that match in the database. Now, while the match is running (every 10 minutes or so), I want the game to send yet another request, confirming that the game is in fact still open.

If no ping has been received, that match record is removed.

Comment: You could just include a 'lastupdatedtimestamp' column and run a regular delete query that 'expires' (deletes) records that haven't been updated in a certain time...

Comment: @sehe, the network must be highly scalable. I think that may overload the server in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a [SQL Server agent Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187880.aspx) that will check a date stamp of a row and delete it if it is "stale".

This would require you to have a `DateUpdated` and/or `DatePinged` column on the table which would be updated every time it is updated/pinged (whatever you mean by pinged).

If you don't have SQL Server agent available, one alternative is to use the [task scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler), possibly with [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx).

Comment: How would I do that? Where can I read more about these SQL jobs?

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen - Link added.

Comment: I don't have the Microsoft SQL Server Agent available on my server. What to do then? Run a separate thread with the cleanup job on it?

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen - You could use the [task scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler), possibly with [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx).